# Fontawesome 5 duplicate identifier

Tags: node.js, angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

How do I load both regular and solid version of `faCircle` (for example) in my angular project?

If I declare in `app.component.ts` the following:

```
import faCircle from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid/faCircle';
import faCircle from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCircle';

fontawesome.library.add(faCircle);
fontawesome.library.add(faCircle);
```

I gonna face the following error during the build process:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(22,9): error TS2300: Duplicate
>   identifier 'faCircle'. src/app/app.component.ts(24,51): error TS2300:
>   Duplicate identifier 'faCircle'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb typescript question...anyway here's the solution I found a couple of minutes later

```
import {faCircle as faCircleSolid} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid';
import {faCircle as faCircleRegular} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular';

fontawesome.library.add(faCircleSolid);
fontawesome.library.add(faCircleRegular);
```